# Repository destroyed after delete from eGit?

Tags: git, repository, egit, recovery, corrupt

I deleted a repository from my egit-perspective in Eclipse. When it asked to delete contents on disk, I answered "no". Finally, a NullPointerException appeared.
Anyway, it seems that my repo has been destroyed. 
When I went in the repo with Git Bash, the path was shown like this:

```
/git/myrepo ((unknown))
```

Unfortunately, I then used git init.
Now, it says I am on branch master, and I can see my other branches too, but when I try to checkout to another branch, it says:

```
git checkout cv_st_views
fatal: reference is not a tree: cv_st_views
```

I tried to clone the corrupted repository, and it says:

```
Cloning into 'myrepo'...
error: unable to find 1aaa3c3aeed586b2b2ee182aacb6fe436e7ea179
error: refs/heads/cv_st_views does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/heads/master does not point to a valid object!
```

I would be able to restore most of the content from a remote repository, but the branch cv_st_views is only in this local repositiory. Is there anything I can do?

**Edit**
git fsck returns this

`Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (36524/36524), done.
error: HEAD: invalid sha1 pointer 1aaa3c3aeed586b2b2ee182aacb6fe436e7ea179
error: refs/heads/cv_st_views does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/heads/master does not point to a valid object!
broken link from  commit 03d8ff939b9f7caa073b14bd4c97949f961eb9f6
              to  commit d272e0305bf416151e711592203542877dd63367
broken link from    tree 38441949a06c71002ed3b7b042f43a5f6efa5046
              to    tree 4bc5f4cdfdf553e20922456f55b04f4f7a99f5d1
broken link from    tree 38441949a06c71002ed3b7b042f43a5f6efa5046
              to    tree b5cf64c2fb8de8430d12cfa9e3cd911228d51b24
broken link from    tree 912ff9e9a73a969976507da71fdde45f27b0fb10
              to    tree ecb1f2408ad803f75b48d0f6c33bb0ff39b220bf
broken link from    tree 28e87a0f1ad9860084a019e719f8a7f7d96e1444
              to    tree facedf9c33377b47b28c88857aeebff0314e5bba
broken link from    tree c6cbe81db1e76c1dc98f1b9a8cc5b4019bb7911c
              to    blob 96d0403fd98bcf9655f044ddf8874d02881615e8
broken link from    tree 8afed21ddf6c1a1e942cb0191899489756be7728
              to    blob c9394d289cd3a6b1bb0bab8701031732e47f21aa
dangling commit 260ad8ef9157c6062e9563757e5002cb932b1a4a
dangling commit 662d4ede0e94c7c7fb9076c69f2e2aab3d9c8ba7
dangling tree 734a842e08bf40f6bee377a763309a95e6b84095
dangling commit 62551a480aa853569eb7b81c749fef9c6a847a4d
dangling commit 605ede65db97c6af5dc947c1d0e23a73f158db59
dangling tree 5d622a08a1d93724819add3cfb7ab9df3b6dfea4
dangling commit 7272845a428936357fb19b2d52363c26744724b1
missing commit d272e0305bf416151e711592203542877dd63367
dangling tree 8e75986a9bf1ed61ed753774429b135b5959d4e2
dangling commit dc82c607cc88d7c85f7b0367e6804f29258654b3
dangling commit d284d8cbe74dead369ff93c46d0df056748b26d7
dangling tree dd847cf7e26b85e393a8aa89eccea0f4bb142087
dangling commit cb9434202b3e71b8fc35be9f5f8de0e1a9d17cea
missing tree ecb1f2408ad803f75b48d0f6c33bb0ff39b220bf
dangling tree 30c46645231e8aa7a2b0e47cb150cfe2806d34db
missing tree 4bc5f4cdfdf553e20922456f55b04f4f7a99f5d1
missing tree b5cf64c2fb8de8430d12cfa9e3cd911228d51b24
missing blob 96d0403fd98bcf9655f044ddf8874d02881615e8
dangling commit 97dcc6dbecdb0d5bcc492940749d76a2b31d0b71
dangling commit 8ae27ce74838a64a08654549b335ebd9db877b87
dangling commit edfc9ace825220c0249d3ead532910fe7f81522c
dangling tree e101adc692c4a7b55471aff5cd3b8ab02b248ddf
missing blob c9394d289cd3a6b1bb0bab8701031732e47f21aa
dangling tree d43abf45d3ca95779a216390580f07731abfe56d
dangling commit 4d3d05147594b0a7c4f67ce4325643f293b0e50c
dangling commit 914a638f7204006c16c6690721cd916010997885
dangling commit 7c4f1ba517930db51d54df2b9f72350ee3ac474f
dangling commit 5e620ff9c2c7611c8744e8faf9843d12d88a4220
dangling commit 69710de551446adec37768bb955e702f2ace346f
dangling commit 5b762946f765d06b0f3adde5bbef05b5ef1571f7
dangling commit bc8789eeb9f7085c4c864956498aaa4ba5e9c897
dangling tree b999bb7f080f405c6c5789ec0ac22daade0afa53
dangling commit 1bbea734c8acfb9d1e97934d9ce0f6a394e0507a
dangling commit f1c44bfe20d8a0e80b5233a8935217ee5eca3172
missing tree facedf9c33377b47b28c88857aeebff0314e5bba
dangling commit e7d0c541cf4d8c1e006b359bcda7e2c7bb011289`

Comment: This sounds pretty serious, and I don't know how EGit could cause this. Do you still have the stack trace from the NullPointerException around? Can you run `git fsck` on the repo?

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I do not have the stack trace, but I added the git fsck output in my original post. Seems that there is quite a mess. Is there any way to repair this stuff?